# QT LimeReport on RPI4

Tags: qt5

I am using QT LimeReport on my UBUNTU 18.04 system although i wanted to use it on RPI4.

But i couldn't find any documentation for it and i tried cloning LimeReport from github but it gives error when i use "make".
The error i get is related to

```
Project ERROR: Unknown module(s) in QT: designercomponents-private
make[1]: *** [Makefile:818: Makefile] Error 3
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/pi/Desktop/LimeReport/limereport'
make: *** [Makefile:93: sub-limereport-make_first-ordered] Error 2
```

Has anyone successfully installed and used LimeReport using QT c++ on RPI4.

Comment: How did you build it on your Pi? Did you use CMake or QMake?

Comment: i used QMake for build.

Comment: Did you use `qmake -r limereport.pro` like [the automated build](https://github.com/fralx/LimeReport/blob/master/.travis.yml#L663) does? Did you install the designer components for Qt as well?

Comment: @Botje i used "qmake -r limereport.pro" and yes i` installed QT designer component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install the [qttools5-private-dev](https://packages.debian.org/buster/qttools5-private-dev) package to get the missing designercomponents-private QMake file.

Comment: ~~~
sudo apt-get install libqt5designercomponents5 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libqt5designercomponents5 is already the newest version (5.11.3-4).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded. 
~~~

Comment: I updated my answer, you're missing a different package.

Comment: Thank you, It worked!
Can you just guide/tell me how did you knew that "qttools5-private-dev" package was missing.

Comment: I did a file search for all paths containing "designercomponents" on packages.debian.org.